# Vue.component vs import to load a component

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

Why when I use `Vue.component` to load the two commented components below, I get the following error in the javascript console while it works with `import` ?

> Uncaught ReferenceError: dashboard is not defined

`app.js`:

```
Vue.component('left-menu', require('./components/LeftMenu.vue').default);
// Vue.component('dashboard', require('./components/foo/dashboard.vue').default);
// Vue.component('members', require('./components/foo/members.vue').default);
import dashboard from './components/foo/dashboard.vue';
import members from './components/foo/members.vue';

const routes = [
    {
        path: '/dashboard',
        component: dashboard
    },
    // {
    //     path: '/members',
    //     component: members
    // }
];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you use `dashboard` variable in your routes, this variable exists in "import way" but not in "Vue component way"

Answer (score 1):

In the example that generates errors the components are not recognized as variables, so you should do something like :

```
const dashboard = {
  template: `<div>Dashboard</div>` ,

}

const routes = [
    {
        path: '/dashboard',
        component: dashboard
    },
    // {
    //     path: '/members',
    //     component: members
    // }
];
```